# Authentication error when ajax code run

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax code behind my button, when I click on button this error occur: (I use Asp.NET)
This is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../portal/ajax.aspx/CalculatePostPrice",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ city: city, transportId: transport, domain: domain, cookie: cookie }),
            success: function (response) {
                $("#<%= this.lbl_Transfer_Price.ClientID %>").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Error!");
            }

        });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0cLg.jpg)

Comment: Show us your code. It sounds like the URL your ajax'ing to requires authentication.

Comment: I think the problem might be your relative path ../../portal/ajax.aspx/CalculatePostPrice is going to the wrong place. If I visit http://www.webpages-panel.com/portal/ajax.aspx/CalculatePostPrice directly there seems to be no requirement to authenticate

Comment: It should work to just replace the relative URL with an absolute path: `/portal/ajax.aspx/CalculatePostPrice`